# Was the family connection established in The Empire Strikes Back?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back, return-of-the-jedi

Every Star Wars fan remembers the uncomfortable moment in The Empire Strikes back where Leia kisses Luke.  In Return of the Jedi we're then told that she's his sister.

While George Lucas and the writers were making The Empire Strikes Back had this family relationship been decided or was it only added for Return of the Jedi?

Comment: I think to remember this was addressed before here, but this may just have been a side information from a different question.

Comment: Related question on [scifi.se]: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/66444/23386.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Source - [Empire Strikes Back FAQ on IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080684/faq#.2.1.4)

> **"There is another." To whom is Yoda referring?**
>
> At the time that *Empire* was written and released, Leia was not meant to be Luke's sister. Luke instead had an unnamed sister, also undergoing Jedi training, on the opposite end of the galaxy.

Leia being Luke's sister was only decided when Return of the Jedi was made.

Comment: Just for fun, I also like to think that that Yoda's famous line might refer to Vader. Yoda knows that Vader's redemption would defeat the Emporer, and he is also bathed in red light when he says it. Nonsense, I know - but it's fun to speculate.

Comment: While the above reference to "There is another" is probably true, it seems a little weird to me. Lucas seems very methodical about the Star Wars universe. I would think such an important point in the story would have already been decided in Lucas' mind. I mean, it really is quintessential to the story line.

Comment: That IMDB page is just an unsourced wiki.  It would be better to link to something that is either a primary source, or at least cites its source.

Comment: @Keen - The source for this claim appears to be the book "The Making of The Empire Strikes Back", however I haven't read it.